# Bootstrap 4 footer displaying over body text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

I'm new to bootstrap and CSS in general so please excuse any newbie nonsense!

I'm doing a basic web app using ASP.NET Core and Bootstrap 4.3.1 using VS 2019.  I seem to be having issues with the layout page where the text from a razor page is overlapping the footer.

[This is how the page appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME1GJ.png)

The body text in the razor page is nothing more than a bunch of h6 and p tags, there is no other formatting or tags, but the page text is quite long.

The markup for the _Layout.cshtml file is below. I've tried changing the z-index of the footer to 99 as was suggested to me but that hasn't worked.  I'm sure the answer is simple and highlights my inate lack of knowledge but any help to stop the body text and footer mixing would be appreciated.

For info this is displayed in Chrome.

Any questions or if I've missed any info, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Start Mortgages</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse flex-sm-row-reverse">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Link1">Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Link2">Link 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Link3">Link 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Link4">Link 4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Link5">Link 5</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Link6">Link 6</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item border-top">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Link7">Link 7</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-3 small overflow-auto">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>
        <footer class="border-top footer text-muted text-center small" style="line-height: 20px;">
            <div class="container pt-3">
                <div class="row pb-3">
                    <div class="col-4 text-left pb-3">
                        Company Name<br />
                        Address 1<br />
                        Address 2<br />
                        Address 3<br />
                        Address 4<br />
                        Address 5
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-left">
                        <div>
                            LINKS
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Link8">Link 8</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Link9">Link 9</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Link10">Link 10</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Link11">Link 11</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-wrap">
                    <div>Company Registration Info</div>
                    <div>Company Regulator Info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce this issue. I've copied your code into https://codepen.io/Oddleik/pen/eYpQaKN, do you experience the same issue when you view that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Henrik, no I don't see the issue in your link. The text that goes in the razor page is quite long (list of ts&cs).  It makes little sense that there could be a limit on the amount of text.
I'll try with half the text, which will still be require scrolling, and see if anything changes.

Comment: You could also try to remove the link to your `site.css`-file to make sure there are no conflicting rules

Comment: Thanks Henrik, removing the link to site.css resolved the issue.  I haven't edited the site.css file, no need to at this early stage, so I'm confused but a quick google search reveals a myriad of issues related to css conflicts so I'm sure I'll encounter it again.
Many thanks again for your help.  As I'm a newbie do you enter it as an answer now?

Comment: No problem. For these types of questions where it's so specific to your particular setup and we were able to solve it in the comments, typically one does not submit an answer. It's a norm though, not a rule, so I can submit it as an answer if you'd like :)